# Xamarin.Forms bindingContext Set the source back to root/parent

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got a `ViewModel` with a command (`AddToFavoriteCommand`) that doesn't get called. Now it only looks after the command in the `CustomPin class`, not the `viewModel`. I'm setting my `viewModel` to the `BindingContext` of the page in the code behind.

But since it enumerates my collection of customPins, it looks after the command there. I need to get back to the root. I probably need to change the source but can't get it to work.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Button Text="{Binding Filter}" Command="{Binding GotoFilterPageCommand}" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomPins}" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Text="Favorite" Command="{Binding AddToFavoriteCommand}" />
                            <MenuItem Text="..." CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Clicked="OnMoreClicked" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding ParkingLot.Street}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind (removed all other logic like clicked events that I didn't needed for this)

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ParkingListPage : ContentPage
{
    public ParkingListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ParkingListViewModel();
    }
}
```

My `ViewModel`

```
public class ParkingListViewModel
{
    public ParkingListViewModel()
    {
        AddToFavoriteCommand = new Command(Test);
    }

    private void Test()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<CustomPin> CustomPins { get; set; } = SampleParkings.Parkings;

    public Command AddToFavoriteCommand { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<ContentPage x:Name="YourPageName">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                <Button Text="{Binding Filter}" Command="{Binding GotoFilterPageCommand}" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView" RowHeight="60" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomPins}" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Favorite" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AddToFavoriteCommand, Source={x:Reference YourPageName}}" />
                                <MenuItem Text="..." CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Clicked="OnMoreClicked" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding ParkingLot.Street}" FontSize="Medium" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Notice how I added the `x:Name` element to the root of the page. Of course there are more attributes there, leave them there, but I left them out for clarity here.

Secondly, notice how I referred to that name from the `MenuItem` binding and added `Path=BindingContext.`. This way it will bind to the `BindingContext` of the element identified by the name, in our case the `ContentPage`.

A sample project can be found here: https://github.com/jfversluis/SampleParentBinding

Comment: Works as you say it should work. Now it's calling the code behind. But I want it to call my viewModel. Now in my code behind I only set my BindingContext like this, BindingContext = new ViewModel(); Should I make a property of my viewModel so I can use the path or something?

Comment: This should work with a view model. Please update your question with the code on how you set the view model.

Comment: I updated my code behind. I removed all other methods like click events. I added my viewModel as well if it matter.

Comment: With the XAML I've posted this should work. Implement some logic in your test method and it should be called.

Comment: Weird, because it doesn't work. It still calls my code behind. I removed it from the code behind to avoid some conflict but still the same. Could this matter in my contentpage tag? xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" , xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

Comment: I'll work out a sample project for you tomorrow if you don't have anything by then

Comment: I actually forgot a smallllll but important detail in the binding of the MenuItem, I've updated the answer and added a sample project. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That helped :)