# Xamarin form: How to reference to the parent binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, binding-context

```
<ViewCell> 
   <ViewCell.View>
      <Label Text="{Binding ABC}"></Label>
   </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Assuming this viewcell was inside ListView. If the content page was binding with a view model, how can I get a reference to the content page's binding. Currently, 'ABC' is referencing the property of an object in the list but i want to get the value from the content page's bindingcontext.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{x:Reference page}" Command="{Binding OnSignInCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Model}" />
</ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms bindingContext Set the source back to root/parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036081/xamarin-forms-bindingcontext-set-the-source-back-to-root-parent)

Answer (score 40):

@qubuss gave the correct answer below, but I would like to give more context and show an example to make it more clear:

Lets consider the following page:

```
<ContentPage  
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="firstPage" -->this reference parent context
    x:Class="Your_Class_Name">
  <ListView x:Name="ListSource"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                         // this come from item source
                    <Label Text="{Binding ABC}"></Label>
                    <Button Command="{Binding BindingContext.CommandFromParent
                           , Source={x:Reference firstPage} }" />
                        </Grid>
                                                
                       </ViewCell>
                  /DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>


</ContentPage>
```

your view Model should look like that

```
 public class ViewModelName 
    {
        private List<YourDataType> _listSource = new List<YourDataType>();
        

        public List<YourDataType> ListSource
        {
            get => _listSource;
            set
            {
                _listSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand CommandFromParent => new Command(HandleYourActionHere);

}
}
```

**Explanation**
When we write `BindingContext.CommandFromParent`, BindingContext represents the BindingContext of `firstPage(x:Name="firstPage")` which is of type `ViewModelName`

Comment: Upvoted for showing that CommandFromParent is a property on the ViewModel and not some fancy XAML syntax

Answer (score 27):

You can bind to an ancestor with a `RelativeSource`.

Change this line

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding ABC}"></Label>
```

to this

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding ABC, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModel:YourViewModelName}}}"></Label>
```

Don't forget to add the xml namespace for `viewModel` on top of the file:

```xml
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:YourProject.ViewModels"
```

You can read all about `RelativeSource` bindings here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor

Comment: Thx, I finally found what I'm looking for!

Comment: Such a useful answer, thank you! FYI, just to add `xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Your.ViewModels;assembly=CS_PROJ_ASSEMBLY_NAME"` if you get the error of a namespace that could not be found, or your xaml/views are in a different project to your viewmodels, etc

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `BindingContext="{x:Reference viewmodel}` inside label.

```
<ViewCell> 
  <ViewCell.View>
    <Label Text="{Binding ABC}" BindingContext="{x:Reference Name_Of_Parent}"></Label>
  </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

in Name_Of_Parent you put name of component. If you use MVVM and ViewModel class you have to add `x:Name` to your binding Context:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <mvvm:MasterPageModel 
    x:Name="viewmodel"/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

This is [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) which describe it.

Comment: My OnSignInCommand not get called. The OnSignInCommand was implemented inside the viewmodel of the page binding context. Where as the Model in CommandParameters was the binding object of the item.

Comment: Please put all xaml, and maybe you need to add references to different parent.

Answer (score 3):

DataContext.Command works for me.

```xml
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Name="firstPage"
    x:Class="Your_Class_Name">
    <ListView x:Name="ListSource" ItemsSource="{Binding ListSource}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ABC}"></Label>
                        <Button Command="{Binding BindingContext.CommandFromParent, Source={x:Reference firstPage} }" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: In Xamarin, you need to use ```BindingContext``` instead of ```DataContext```

Answer (score 3):

Give content page a name:

```
<ContentPage x:Name="this">
```

Access page's binding context like this:

```
  <Label BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=BindingContext}" >
```